# Why hash functor with non-const operator () does not compile in Visual Studio, when working with unordered set?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operator-overloading

I've reduced the code that originaly cause me the pain to a simple example:

a class with a dummy equality operator:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    bool operator==(const MyClass& mc)  {
        return false;
    }
};
```

then a dummy hash functor for that class:

```
template<> struct std::hash<MyClass> {
        size_t operator()(const MyClass& s) {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

and the main method:

```
int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<MyClass> set_1;
    std::unordered_set<MyClass> set_2;
    set_1 = set_2;

    return 0;
}
```

In visual studio, this generates an error:

```
error C3848: expression having type 'const _Hasher' would lose some const-volatile qualifiers in order to call 'size_t std::hash<MyClass>::operator ()(const MyClass &)'
```

After hours of debugging, I've found out that the cause of the bug is the non-const hash functor, i.e., it works when I change the signature to: `size_t operator()(const MyClass& s) const`

However, in GCC, it generates no error (only warning about unused parameters), and it Clang, it generates only a warning:

```
warning: the specified hash functor does not provide a viable const call operator
```

So **my question is**, why this code does not compile in Visual Studio? I know it does not make any sense to have a non-const hash functor, but I haven't found any reason why it shouldn't compile.

Moreover, despite VS signalize the error on the `set_1` declaration line, the code compiles fine if I remove the assignment from `set_1` to `set_2`.

Comment: Because it is ill-formed. Predicates must be const. gcc only accepts this until you attempt to invoke the predicate from a `const` container instance, then it will blow up. VS just gives you an earlier notice that your predicate lacks a suitable const operator.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you.